# How do I get my ACTUAL User Agent using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to make a script to get some weather data from the web. Problem is, the tools I'm using crash when I use the wrong user-agent, meaning it could be a valid one but if it's not the right one it crashes.

I tried:

```
from getuseragent import UserAgent
useragent = UserAgent("all")
theuseragent = useragent.Random()
```

and it works most of the time. But it doesn't always work, and when it doesn't, it crashes.

So I just wanted a way to get my ACTUAL user agent, not a fake or random one. Can anyone help me?

By the way, I am using the requests_html do interact with the browser.

By the way, as of now, this part of the code goes:

```
def prepare_request(city):
    
    session = HTMLSession()
    url = f"https://www.bing.com/search?q=weather+{city}"
    request = session.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"})
    return request
```

Edit:
This is the error I get when I get the wrong user agent from useragent.Random()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luis-jose/Desktop/cse111/Week 6/what_is_the_weather.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/luis-jose/Desktop/cse111/Week 6/what_is_the_weather.py", line 10, in main
    temperature = get_data(request, "div.wtr_currTemp.b_focusTextLarge")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/luis-jose/Desktop/cse111/Week 6/what_is_the_weather.py", line 42, in get_data
    data = (request.html.find(selector, first=True).text)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: add the header `user-agent` with exact value that works. for example if edge works then you can add `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/111.0.1661.54`

Comment: @peeyushpathak the question is how to find out that value. OP already understands how to add the header.

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to view the request headers sent to a remote site.

Comment: Yes, it works great in my machine, and up until now I was doing just that. But I want to make sure it will work wherever. I'll edit it now so it gets clear. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, this is not a question about programming. The way to find out your browser's user-agent is using your browser's developer tools, or else looking up a web service that will report back the headers that you sent it when you visited the web page - such as https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/ . I found that, btw, by putting `get my browser's user-agent header` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=get+my+browser%27s+user-agent+header). Please try to [do basic research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking.

Comment: I don't understand what you're really asking for.  Whatever tool you're using to fetch this weather data (whether that is an actual browser, or the `requests_html` package, or something else) should set its own user_agent header.  Why do you need to set that header at all?

Comment: I know how to get my own. I want the program to get that for me. So it works on other places as well. And maybe that's just me being dumb, but I spent more than an hour looking it up online. I found ways to get fake ones, the most used ones and etc... but not mine. I actually used requests_html to get it, but it came back different from the one I get when I google it, and it didn't work.

Comment: @JohnGordon maybe it does, but I don't know how. I didn't see any mentions of it in the documentation either. I'll look it up again, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: What do you mean, "actual" user agent? The user agent is a way for the client to pass an identifier to the server; it's not something that's *assigned* to you. If you want to *impersonate* another client, you need to figure out what user agent that client sends, but it's not something the client typically exposes via any kind of API.

Comment: @chepner Okay, maybe I used a wrong wording, I don't even understand what an user agent is, what I want is a way for the code to work without having to write the string in it. Does that make sense? I mean, like a variable, which is what I did using "theuseragent". The problem being, it doesn't work every single time. 

So, whatever the user agent is, I want the code to work without me or the person that receives the .py having to go online to copy and paste it in the headers. 

Thanks for trying to understand my question

Comment: You rarely need any particular user agent, but if you do, it's because the remote server is using it to filter requests it will respond to.

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to include the errors you're getting when the useragent doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can relate to your question, I had the same problem when I was trying to load data from the SEC.

My first solution was googling for "what is my user agent" and then manually entering the provided string into my script, which was kind of annoying.

Here is the old code, I use requests.get() for fetching data from the web:

```
from requests import get

# enter user-agent here manually
useragent = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

try:
    answer = get(link_to_sec_text, headers=useragent, timeout=5)
except ConnectionError as con_error:
    print(con_error)
```

After doing some research and try&error, I found a simple solution using Selenium and replacing the useragent line above with 3 lines of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
useragent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
driver.quit()
```

I have a Windows OS, but I suppose this also works with MacOS, you just need to change the webdriver.Chrome() call to your main browser.